# Doing a FULL OUTER JOIN in Sqlite3 to get the combination of two columns?

Tags: sql, sqlite, left-join, outer-join

I'm currently working on a database project and one of the problems calls for the following:

> The Genre table contains twenty-five entries. The MediaType table contains 5
>   entries. Write a single SQL query to generate a table with three columns and 125
>   rows. One column should contain the list of MediaType names; one column
>   should contain the list of Genre names; the third column should contain a count of
>   the number of tracks that have each combination of media type and genre. For
>   example, one row will be: “Rock MPEG Audio File xxx” where xxx is the
>   number of MPEG Rock tracks, even if the value is 0.

Recognizing this, I believe I'll need to use a **FULL OUTER JOIN**, which Sqlite3 doesn't support. The part that is confusing me is generating the column with the combination. Below, I've attached the two methods I've tried.

```
create view T as
select MediaTypeId, M.Name as MName, GenreId, G.Name as GName
from MediaType M, Genre G

SELECT DISTINCT GName, MName, COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM T 
           OUTER LEFT JOIN MediaType
                ON MName = GName
    UNION ALL
        SELECT *
        FROM Genre
               OUTER LEFT JOIN T
) GROUP BY GName, MName;
```

However, that returned nearly 250 rows and the `GROUP BY` or `JOIN`(s) is totally wrong.

I've also tried:

```
SELECT Genre.Name as GenreName, MediaTypeName, COUNT(*)
    FROM Genre LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT MediaType.Name as MediaTypeName, Track.Name as TrackName
            FROM MediaType LEFT OUTER JOIN Track) GROUP BY GenreName, MediaTypeName;
```

Which returned 125 rows but they all had the same count of **3503** which leads me to believe the `GROUP BY` is wrong.

Also, here is a schema of the database:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/onnbwqfrfc82r1t/IMG_2429.png?dl=0

Comment: next time try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
much faster

Comment: Had no idea that existed @JuanCarlosOropeza, but will definitely use that next time. Thanks!

Comment: Much better than a picture ;) Also you could include some sample data and require output

Answer (score 2):

You don't use `full outer join` to solve this problem.

Because it looks like a homework problem, I'll describe the solution.

First, you want to generate all combinations of genres and media types. Hint: This uses a `cross join`.

Second, you want to count all the combinations that you have. Hint: this uses an aggregation.

Third, you want to combine these together. Hint: left join.